# Non Domain external user getting error while accessing document

Tags: permissions

In SharePoint 2010 site I have a document library and have given non domain users permission to access the library one of the group is given no delete permission and a non domain user from that group is getting an error "we cannot do that for you because the file was deleted or checked out " . What could be the issue when he is trying to access this document in IE. Can anyone help me on this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troubleshooted the issue and finally resolved.

Ianted to post here so that it helps others after going through different trials and reading the user deleting them and again adding them to group, asking them to upload document and try to check out and edit on them did not helped much.

I have gone through these steps and helped me in resolving in the issue.

SharePoint Workspace was running in the system tray which had the "Shared Documents" library synced, because of this there were some temp files out there in the following location

```
c:\Users\login_user_name\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache
```

After terminating the Sharepoint workspace and clearing those temp files, I was able to open documents in Office client.

And other thing is mentioned as in Microsoft

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/899709

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening when the users accesses the document library and then selects the document or are they using a direct link to the document?

If they are using a direct link give them a document library link and ask them to open it.

Comment: hi brian no when the users are trying to access the document libray and select the document it is getting opened with check out being asked and once the user clicks on check out the above error pops up. The user is in a group which has permission level no delete. let me know how to resolve this.